# Serial Downvoting Script failed

Tags: discussion, downvotes, serial-voting

If you take a look at my rep tab on Stack Overflow it appears someone went around and downvoted a bunch of my posts. It was obviously the same person because it was done all at the same time.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2612547/c-sharper?tab=reputation

I saw this person's profile who was also clearly a victim of the same.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1330137/no1-melman?tab=reputation

7 of his questions were downvoted within 3 minutes (-14) but his reversal only gave him +8.

It appears to me the script didn't do it's job correctly and I don't want to be a victim as well. It looks like the only downvotes reversed were the votes occurred at 9:01. -- 9:00 and 8:58 were not taken into account.

I know the script runs in the early morning so I will wait for my rep to be refunded, but
It looks like the script didn't do it's job in `No1_Melman's` case and I would just like to bring attention to the fact.

Comment: The script runs once a day at night...be patient.

Comment: At 3am UTC if I'm correct. So check back tomorrow.

Comment: @bluefeet, I understand that, but it's clear to me that No1_Melman should have +14 reversed but not clear to the script

Comment: If something is amiss there, the particular user can follow the advice here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't worry, the script will catch these blatant serial votes... once it runs.

As @bluefeet noted in her comment - these run nightly, not continually.

If after 48 hours they have not been reversed, then take it to meta ;)